# Multiple Versions of a Windows 10 App

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-universal

We publish an app to the Apple and Android stores that have multiple versions.  Let's call them Pro and Lite, but there are more.  The differences are fairly significant, including large differences in the amount of data available and features.  Android has a feature called flavors to handle this.

1. Is there such a thing as this in the Windows world?
2. Maybe I have to actually create multiple apps in the store?
3. How do I handle this in Visual Studio.  Multiple csproj's?
4. If multiple csproj's, how does one share common xaml views across projects?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a "shared project" for common code/views etc.  Then make new win10 projects for each store app.

You can even put the App.xaml inside the shared project.

IMO I hate multiple projects because of the complexity.  It's much easier sometimes just to have a runtime check what "mode" you are.  Which can be some global constant. But since I think you need to do multiple store submissions- when creating your app package you'll have to reassociate to the targeting store app.

If you have the time my suggestion is shared project with everything in it except the Package.appxmanifest.  Then separate projects with their own Package.appxmanifest defined.  But all that will get you is so you don't have to reassociate the app when making an app package.